# Stack push using external function

Tags: c++, class, stack

I'm trying to implement stacks using constructors in C++. I'm required to use an external function to push an element on the stack, however, it doesn't seem to work properly. The pushexternal function seems to "enter" the push function, but it doesn't increase the ind value, therefore it doesn't add a new element onto the stack (for example in my code, all pushxternals will try to push a value onto the same index, the last one used by s.push - ind==2). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Oh, I'm only supposed to modify the class code - the pushexternal and main have to remain unchanged.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack {
    public:
    int ind;
    int * arr;

Stack()
{
    arr = new int[25];
    ind = -1;
}
~Stack()
{
    delete [] arr;
}

void push(int val)
{
    arr[++ind] = val;
    cout << "Added " << arr[ind] << " to " << ind << endl;
}

void top()
{
    cout << "Last: " << arr[ind];
}
};

void pushexternal(Stack s, int a) {
    s.push(a);
}

int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.push(0);
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    pushexternal(s, 3);
    pushexternal(s, 4);
    pushexternal(s, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Added 0 to 0
Added 1 to 1
Added 2 to 2
Added 3 to 3
Added 4 to 3
Added 5 to 3
Top: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void pushexternal(Stack s, int a) {
    s.push(a);
}
```

receives a Stack as a parameter, which means it receives an object which is a copy of your object.

You should operate on references, this way you will not send a copy of the object to be manipulated, but the reference of the object, thus the original object will be manipulated.

Comment: Thank you, passing by reference works properly. However, it requires me to change the pushexternal function (void pushexternal(Stack &s, int a)). In this task, the book I'm using wants me to keep the pushexternal and main functions unchanged and only change the code of my class. I'm not sure as I haven't yet tried it, but would using a copy construtor help in this case?

Comment: A copy constructor is used to initialize an object with data from an already existing object. That wouldn't help you as your function takes Stack from the function parameter and operates on it. My guess is, the example is either wrong or the book want you to find the "mistake".

Answer (score 1):

```
void pushexternal(Stack s, int a) {
    s.push(a);
}
```

You are passing the `Stack` object to this function by value, not by reference. This makes a temporary copy of the original `Stack` object, so the original object remains unchanged. Not to mention that this will result in memory corruption, since the `RAII` principle has been violated.

Just by the luck of the draw, I guess, your code is not segfaulting.